# Spring Api remove empty field from reponse

Tags: json, spring, api, rest, filter

I would like to filter any empty, null or default empty objects from a json serialized response to minimize the output to the minimum.

I found this article: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria

It is kind of what I want, but I don't have a specific DTO. I would like to use it on any response with a anotation or something like that. But I can't find any tutorial for this.

Comment: Consider reading the Jackson documentation for configuration options. You can't use annotations when you don't have an object to put the annotation on.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it works with `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter`, but I don't know how to get it wired all together.